# How to access case class field annotation values

Tags: scala, reflection, annotations, case-class

I have a case class for which I add some annotation to some of the fields:

```
final class Anno(min: Int, max: Int) extends StaticAnnotation

case class Test(x: String, @Anno(min = 5, max = 10) y: String)
```

I would like to iterate each field of the case class, get its value and the case class annotation properties assigned to it (if annotation exists).

Any idea how can it be accomplished in Scala?

Comment: You'll find most of the answers in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468571/how-to-access-annotation-defined-on-case-class-field-at-runtime

Comment: Thanks. Already saw it. Didn't help so much... Returned an empty list. I already have a solution for getting list of annotations, but with no reference to the original case class parameters and also I am not sure how to access the annotation properties, once I have an annotation class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the list of annotations of the constructor of the case class you can use:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
symbolOf[Test].asClass.primaryConstructor.typeSignature.paramLists.head.map(s => (s -> s.annotations))
```

However the annotations in the parameter list will not automatically be added to the corresponding class member. So you would have to match the annotated parameter `y` that you get with the above call to the generated field `y` by name.

Alternatively you could annotated the annotation in your case class like this

```
import scala.annotation.meta._
case class Test(x: String, @(Anno @field)(min = 5, max = 10) y: String)
```

and then use

```
val it = symbolOf[Test].toType.members
  .filter(_.annotations.exists(a => a.tree.tpe <:< typeOf[Anno]))
```

to get an iterable of the fields with the `Anno` annotation.
For a found field and an instance of `Test` you get the value as follows

```
val yField = it.iterator.next
val o = Test("123", "abc")
universe.runtimeMirror(o.getClass.getClassLoader).reflect(o)
  .reflectField(yField.asTerm).get
```

Comment: Trying to replace Test with a generic T I am getting this exception: scala.ScalaReflectionException: free type T is not a class. Any way of solving it?

Comment: The first solution seems to get a map of the annotations properly. I am currently iterating the case class and converting it to String using something like: testCaseClass.productIterator.map(_.tostring).mkString("", "|", ""). Any way of iterating the case class in a way I can have access to the map of the first solution?

Comment: your help will be much appreciated. The top solution looks good, I basically have 2 issues with it: 1) How can I access the Annotation info? 2) How can this same code be written with a generic T instead of Test?

Comment: If you declare your type parameter with `[T : TypeTag]` your method will get an implicit parameter and you can use `typeOf[T]` inside it

Comment: It compiles but returns an empty result. I try something like: def extractAnnotations[T: TypeTag]: Unit = {
        val allAnnotations = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass.primaryConstructor.typeSignature.paramLists.head.map(_.annotations) }. When I take it out of the method and enter the case class directly it seems to work: typeOf[TestCaseClass].typeSymbol.asClass.primaryConstructor.typeSignature.paramLists.head.map(_.annotations). Any way of solving it?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Works GREAT. Thanks.

Comment: I have one last issue... I created a method that looks like: AnnotationUtil.annotationsOf[T]. I use it in a class that has a generic T which defined as:  class SomeClass[T <: CC]. And CC is defined as: trait CC extends Product. I get an error on the method since the type is not "TypeTag". Any way of solving it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't completely understand the last comment. Could you maybe extend your question or create a new one?