# Annotating case class parameters

Tags: scala, annotations, case-class

I am trying to annotate a parameter of a case class.

Judging from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468571/how-to-access-annotation-defined-on-case-class-field-at-runtime/28279648), and
and from this [scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/meta/index.html), it looks like what I am doing should work, but for some reason it does not:

```
class Foo extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation { def annotationType = getClass }
case class Bar(@Foo @getter bar: String) 
classOf[Bar].getDeclaredMethods.map(_.getDeclaredAnnotations.length)

res66: Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Write your annotation in Java. Also `@getter` should be used as a **meta**-annotation.

*Foo.java*

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Foo {
}
```

*Bar.scala*

```
case class Bar(@(Foo @getter) bar: String)
```

Then

```
classOf[Bar].getDeclaredMethods.map(_.getDeclaredAnnotations.length)
// Array(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

[Why annotations written in Scala are not accessible at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647213/why-annotations-written-in-scala-are-not-accessible-at-runtime)

Comment: I know how to write it in java, thanks. My question is about scala.

Comment: My answer is about Scala. You should write annotation in Java and use it in Scala.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/81qzs2/how_to_write_annotations_in_scala/dv560g4/

Comment: that sucks ... :(